# Determine an elements position in a variable length grid of elements

Tags: php, javascript, switch-statement

I have a grid of a variable number of elements. Say 5 images per row and a variable number of images. I need to determine which column (for lack of a better word) each image is in... i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

In this grid, images 1, 6, 12 and 17 would be in column 1 while 4, 9 and 15 would be in column 4.

```
1  2  3  4  5 
6  7  8  9  10
12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19
```

What I am trying to do is apply a background image to each element based on it's column position.

An example of this hard coded and inflexible but working perfectly (and if I'm barking up the wrong tree here by all means tell me how you'd ideally accomplish this as it always bugs me when I see someone ask "How do I build a gold plated, solar powered jet pack to get to the top of this building?" when they really should be asking "Where's the elevator?"):

```
switch (imgnum){
                case "1" : case "6" : case "11" :
                    value = "1";
                    break;
                case "2" : case "7" : case "12" :
                    value = "2";
                    break;
                case "3" : case "8" : case "13" :
                    value = "3";
                    break;
                case "4" : case "9" : case "14" :
                    value = "4";
                    break;
                case "5" : case "10" : case "15" :
                    value = "5";
                    break;
                default :
                    value = "";
            }

            $('.someclass > ul').css('background','url("/img/'+value+'.png") no-repeat');
```

Oh, more info... the value for `imgnum` in that switch is determined by a click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulus operator for this type of work. The modulus operator gives you the remainder of an integer division. The modulus operator is `%` in both PHP and JS:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/Modulus.htm

You can replace your entire code block with this:

```
value = imgnum % 5;
if(value == 0) { value = 5; }
$('.someclass > ul').css('background','url("/img/'+value+'.png") no-repeat');
```

Comment: Oh, sure, if you want to take the EASY route ;)

Comment: Where is this just the easy route? I think it's the correct way to solve it. The modulus operator can be used in PHP too, if you want to do it on the server side (just append a dollar sign in front of the variables and you're good to go).

Answer (score 1):

```
$row_num = int($imgnum/5, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);

$column_num = (($row_num * 5) - $imgnum)*-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery nth child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), assuming you're doing this on the client:

> The index of each child to match,
>   starting with 1, the string even or
>   odd, or an equation ( eg.
>   :nth-child(even), :nth-child(4n) )

The column number would be the index modulo 5.

Comment: This is a little overkill. No need to add another entire library to your setup when you have all the tools you need in PHP.

Comment: The corollary is also true: PHP itself is overkill when you can do it in the browser.